# Is it possible to do type casting inside an each block in svelte

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, svelte

I have these types:

```
type Exercise = {
 type: string
 prompt: string
 answer: string
}

type ComplexExercise = {
  type: string
  prompt: string,
  subExercises: Exercise[]
}
```

Im trying to make a component that fetches data from an api and renders it according to the type

```html
<script lang="ts">
  let promise = getExercise(params.exerciseId).then((ex) => (exercise = ex));
  let exercise: ComplexExercise | Exercise;
</script>
...

{#await promise}
  <p>Loading exercise</p>
{:then}
  {#if exercise.type !== "COMPLEX"}
    <BaseEditor {exercise} />
  {:else}
    {#each exercise.subExercises as ex}
      <BaseEditor {ex} />
    {/each}
  {/if}
{/await}
```

I get the following error

```sh
Property 'subExercises' does not exist on type Exercise
```

Casting it  throws this error

```html
{#each (exercise as ComplexExercise).subExercises as ex}
                 ^ Unexpected token svelte(parse-error)
```

Only thing that seems work is setting exercise type to any, I'm avoiding it for the obvious reason.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Typescript is only supported within the `<script>` tags, not in the markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your types to use discriminated union types. That means, there is a common property on which TS can determine which concrete type it is. In your case that property is `type`. Assuming you only have these two exercise types:

```
type Exercise = {
 type: "SIMPLE"
 prompt: string
 answer: string
}

type ComplexExercise = {
  type: "COMPLEX"
  prompt: string,
  subExercises: Exercise[]
}
```

If you do this, TS will know through `{#if exercise.type !== "COMPLEX"}` that in the else block the type is `ComplexExercise` and the type error will go away.

More on discriminated unions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: This works for me well since I don't have many types and they are very unlikely to change, thanks alot